# SQL multiple occurrences of same variables and max function

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date

Here is my table

```
serial Number   Job Date
            1   12/12/2013
            1    1/2/2014
            1    2/23/2010
            1    3/15/2010
            2    11/11/2012
            2    6/5/2011
            2    1/23/2010
```

I want only serial number which have job date older that 12/31/2013, in the above table it should be only the serial number 2 and the latest job date which is 11/11/2012

The result table should be

serial Number   Job Date

2              11/11/2012

@ohho

using where will not work since it will also display the row,

Serial_number    Job Date

1                          12/12/2013

2                           11/11/2012

select serial_number, max(job_date) from computers

where job_date < '2013-12-31'

Group by serial_number

Comment: use WHERE to filter the date out?

Comment: This does not show any effort at all.

Comment: using where will not work since it will also display the row,
Serial_number    Job Date

1                          12/12/2013

2                           11/11/2012


select serial_number, max(job_date) from computers 

where job_date < '2013-12-31'

Group by serial_number

Comment: You are looking for a `HAVING` clause, not a `WHERE` clause. e.g. `SELECT ... GROUP BY serial_number HAVING MAX(job_date) <  '2013-12-31'`

Answer (score 0):

Question is not very clear. As I understand, you are looking for all the serialnumbers which do not have any jobdate greater than or equal to 12/31/3013.
If so, below query will work.

```
select serialnumber -- if you want the biggest serialnumber, use max(serialnumber) 
from myTable tt
where not exists (select * from myTable where serialnumber = tt.serialnumber 
                  and jobdate > '12/31/3013')
```